# How to get latest messages from Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm writing a work management application in C# for my team at work (because our stupid employer didn't give us any appropriate tools). I need to check for new messages in Outlook every once in a while and I need to get messages since the last time I checked them.

I've tried the `Items.Restrict()` method and used the filter `"[ReceivedTime] > ' "+lastUpdate+" ' "`, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I've probably tried every possible format of `lastUpdate` - converted to universal time, to string, to US date/time format. NOTHING works correctly. It either gives me messages in absolutely different time range or doesn't find any msgs at all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm also thinking about using `AdvancedSearch()` but will it be easy and quick to implement? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Can you not just move items to another folder after processing them? That way you know the only messages in the inbox folder are ones you haven't processed, thereby keeping this folder small.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to move messages and moreover, other users can move the messages in Outlook itself so I need to check for the latest messages in each folder every time I do the update cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've wasted some more time on this and found a simplier solution which doesn't force me to rewrite my whole application from scratch.

Instead of using the `Items.Restrict()` method to get the latest messages I'm using `Items.Sort()` to sort them by ReceivedTime and then loop through the first messages from the Items list until I find a message which is older than my last update timestamp.

Example:

```
givenFolder.Items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", true); //true means, it will be descending (latest at the beginning)
```

This solution, unfortunately, has a drawback because `Items.Sort()` seems to work only in Exchange mailbox (doesn't sort properly in ordinary POP mailbox) but I need it only for Exchange anyway, so it's enough for me.

I think, it's also possible to use Outlook's AdvancedSearch or MAPI tables but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer, take a look at *Exchange Web Services Managed API 1.2 SDK* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=EXCHG.80).aspx. It is much easier to deal with, is so much more flexible, and with no dependency on Outlook.

*Working with search by using the EWS Managed API*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633671(v=exchg.80).aspx

*Working with search filters by using the EWS Managed API*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633659(v=exchg.80).aspx

Look for a MAPI Viewer. Microsoft provides one and there are others. With the viewer, you can look at the folder and item properties to see how you need to filter.

Yet, I think the examples in *Working with search filters by using the EWS Managed API* will get  you going.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come across this question, a similar one was asked and answered here: [Restrict Outlook Items by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/restrict-outlook-items-by-date)

This is the documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict

The date has to be formatted like so: `M/d/yy h:mm tt` (in .NET date format string) Example: May 6, 2007 at 8:09 AM becomes `5/6/07 8:09 AM` Full filter string then becomes `[ReceivedTime] >= '5/6/07 8:09 AM'` (single quotes are important)

Answer (score 0):

An example how I fixed this using the documentation that also Mr. TA refers too:

```
            string filterDateString = lastUpdate.Day + "/" + lastUpdate.Month + "/" + lastUpdate.Year + " " + filterDate.ToShortTimeString();
            string filter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" + filterDateString + "'";

            Application outlookApplication = new Application();
            NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Items mailItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

EDIT: filterDate.ToShortTimeString() only works in the right way if your CultureInfo is ("en-us") otherwise you need to add AM or PM or do this:

```
CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = us;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not connecting directly to your mail server and issuing POP3 or IMAP commands through a simple connection ? I used to do that directly in telnet ages ago. Commands are pretty simple and should work also under windows. ([for ref see this](http://techhelp.santovec.us/pop3telnet.htm))

Another way may be opening directly the Outlook folder, but this will imply that a client version of Outlook is actually running and downloading messages from the server.

Btw, a program which tells you if you've got new mail already exists, is called biff (and I suspect it exists even on MS platform).

Comment: 1. It's an Exchange mailbox so it's not so easy to connect to the server directly
2. We are obliged to use Outlook because we need to mark messages in a specific way and I want my application to do that for us
3. We do have a client version of Outlook. We have to but iterating through each MailItem in a folder will take hours when you have a few thousand mail and this is useless when you just need to get the few lates maessages
4. I don't need a program to check if I've got new mail. I need the new messages themselves! And I need them from Outlook because we have to work with Outlook

Comment: try out some commands in telnet. Exchange "knows" POP3 and IMAP. Accessing directly via MAPI can be another option. Even good old ole automation from withing Visual Basic can be a good choice.

Comment: At this point I think it's better use some MAPI control to interface directly Exchange and query for new messages, then use their ID to access them directly on the PST file and mark them as you want. Connecting to exchange via MAPI is not that hard, if you've got Outlook working, then you can do it.

Comment: But EntryID is not unique globally and will change whenever a user moves the message to a different folder. If I check for new messages on Exchange server and get their EntryID's, I might not be able to find them in Outlook afterwards because someone might move a message right after it's been downloaded.
Moreover, I will probably still have to use the very same Items.Restrict() method to find latest messages on the Exchange server, am I wrong?