# Restrict Outlook Items by Date

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook macro that filters email objects by date and returns items based on an array.

The filter for today is the following:

```
sfilter = "[ReceivedTime]>=""&Date()12:00am&"""
Set myItems = myNewFolder.Items.Restrict(sfilter)
```

sFilter is a string and this returns the items for today as intended.

I am trying to filter to emails received yesterday.

The following were my attempts.

```
sfilter = "[ReceivedTime]>=""&Date(-1) 12:00am&"" AND [ReceivedTime]<= ""&Date() 12:00am&"" "
tfilter = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy")
rFilter = Format(DateAdd("d", 0, Date), "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I intended to use the tFilter and rFilter as the upper and lower bound for sFilter.

I tried to use the DateAdd method after looking on the MSDN site with the function information but that did not return yesterday's items.

I tried the solution offered on this question ([Outlook .Restrict method does not work with Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395382/outlook-restrict-does-not-work-with-date)).

The method with date(-1) did not work in tandem with date. According to the MSDN site logical operators should work.

Note: The lower three examples cited compile and do not return any errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find yesterday's mail with two separate [Restricts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).

```
Private Sub EmailYesterday()

Dim oOlInb As Folder
Dim oOlItm As Object

Dim oOlResults As Object
Dim i As Long

Dim sFilter As String
Dim sFilter2 As String

Set oOlInb = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Filter recent - Lower Bound of the range
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime]>'" & format(Date - 1, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"

Debug.Print vbCr & sFilter
Set oOlResults = oOlInb.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
Debug.Print oOlResults.count & " items."

If oOlResults.count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To oOlResults.count
        Set oOlItm = oOlResults(i)
        Debug.Print oOlItm.Subject & " - " & oOlItm.ReceivedTime
    Next i
End If

' Filter range - Upper Bound
sFilter2 = "[ReceivedTime]<'" & format(Date, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"

Debug.Print vbCr & sFilter; " AND " & sFilter2

Set oOlResults = oOlResults.Restrict(sFilter2)   ' Restrict the Lower Bound result
Debug.Print oOlResults.count & " items."

If oOlResults.count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To oOlResults.count
        Set oOlItm = oOlResults(i)
        Debug.Print oOlItm.Subject & " - " & oOlItm.ReceivedTime
    Next i
End If
    
ExitRoutine:
    Set oOlInb = Nothing
    Set oOlResults = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! The filtering is working but is there a way to include time with the filter? The code you provided seems to be returning some items from today as well. Does this mean that it is returning items < today @ current time? I tried adding the time in the same way I did above but outlook does not seem to like that.

Comment: It also seems that ReceivedTime = & Date - 1 returns no items. I'm guessing this is due to current time being used. Would the sent on property of mail items avoid this issue? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172005(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Seems to have been a bit more complex than first thought. Added date formatting to the filter. I think I tested a little better than before.

Comment: Thanks! It's working perfectly now. Just one more quick question. If I wanted to change the time how would I go about doing it? Would I have to use dateadd or would I need to put in a string with the desired time?

Comment: You can see how a time is added here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx   sFilter = "[ReceivedTime]>'" & format(Date - 1 & " 11:30am", "DDDDD HH:NN ampm") & "'"

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday date could be filtered as below

```
oOlResults.Restrict("@SQL=%yesterday(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
```

The same for today or this month.

```
 oOlResults.Restrict("@SQL=%today(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
 oOlResults.Restrict("@SQL=%thismonth(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison)