# Grab an email with specific subject that was received today only

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am trying to pull an email from outlook and grab the excel table that was attached in that email. The code works fine, except the fact that I can't understand how to let VBA  code to grab only today's email, otherwise it keeps grabbing previous days email and saving numerous files with the current date.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ExportOutlookTableToExcel()
Dim oLookInspector As Inspector
Dim oLookMailitem As MailItem

Dim oLookWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim oLookWordTbl As Word.Table

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Grab Email Item
 Set oLookMailitem = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items("Apples Sales")

 Set oLookInspector = oLookMailitem.GetInspector

 Set oLookWordDoc = oLookInspector.WordEditor

 'Create a New Excel App
 Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlWrkSheet = xlBook.Worksheets.Add

Set oLookWordTbl = oLookWordDoc.Tables(2)
oLookWordTbl.Range.Copy
xlWrkSheet.Paste Destination:=xlWrkSheet.Range("A1")
xlBook.SaveAs FileName:="xxx" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877302/4539709

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the `Items` collection first, then grab the first match:

```
set folder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
set items = fodler.Items
items.Sort "ReceivedTime", true 'sort in descending order
set oLookMailitem = items.Find("[Subject] = 'Apples Sales'")
if not (oLookMailitem is Null) Then
  ..
End If
```

Comment: Get rid of parentheses (see above).

Comment: If the post answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find only today's emails in Outlook you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, to find items on a specific date you can use the following code in C#:

```
private void FindItems(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
    string dateTimeStart = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,
                               DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    string dateTimeEnd = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
    string searchCriteria = "[ReceivedTime]<=\"" + dateTimeEnd + "\"";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
    int counter = default(int);
    Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
    Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
    object resultItem = null;
    try
    {
        folderItems = folder.Items;
        folderItems.Sort("[ReceivedTime]");
        if (folderItems.Count > 0)
        {
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria);
            if (resultItem != null)
            {
                strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                do
                {
                    if (resultItem is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        mailItem = resultItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                        strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                                              "\tSubject: " + appItem.Subject);
                    }
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem);
                    resultItem = folderItems.FindNext();
                }
                while (resultItem != null);
            }
        }
        if (strBuilder != null)
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
        else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " +
                               folder.Name + " folder.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
    }
}
```

In VBA you can use the `Format` function which prepares the date time object for using in Outlook search conditions:

```
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format("12/28/2021 0:00am", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

Note, you can combine the search string with any other properties like the `Subject` line. Just use the `AND` operator in the search string. Read more about string operators in the [String (for Text fields)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict#string-for-text-fields) section.

Also you may find the `AdvancedSearch` method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about this method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Comment: When I am using Restrict(sFilter)  `Set oLookInspector = Items.GetInspector` shows: "Object doesn't support this property or method". Here is my additions to the code:` sFilter = "[Subject] = 'APPLES SALES' AND [ReceivedTime] = '" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"   Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(sFilter)   Set oLookInspector = Items.GetInspector`

Comment: The `GetInspector` method is available to Outlook items such MailItem, AppointmentItem and etc. But it seems you are trying to call it against the `Items` collection object. Instead, get an item from a collection and call the `GetInspector` method.