# Copying table from a specific date and subject from Outlook mail to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, copy

Every day I receive an email with the subject title "Email subject ABC" with a table in it. Some days I copy this table onto Excel to process the data.

I want with a macro to pull the table with the email subject "Email subject ABC", from a specified date, and copy it onto Cell B2 of the worksheet tab named "Tab DEF" in the currently open workbook.

I get:

> Run-time error '13':
> Type mismatch

The line with `Next olMail` is highlighted.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportOutlookTableToExcel()

Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInboxFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olMailCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Declare Excel Variables
Dim olWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim olWordTable As Word.Table

'Declare Excel Variables
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set olNS = GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set olInboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olInboxFolder)
Set olItems = olInboxFolder.Items

i = 1
olMailCount = olItems.Count

Dim Start_date As Date
Dim End_date As Date

Start_date = #12/8/2020# + TimeSerial(5, 0, 0)
End_date = #12/10/2020# + TimeSerial(5, 0, 0)

'Searching every item in the inbox
For Each olItems In olInboxFolder.Items
    If olItems.CreationTime >= Start_date And olItems.CreationTime <= End_date Then
        If olItems.Subject = "Email subject" Then

            Set olInspector = olItems.GetInspector

            Set olWordDoc = olInspector.WordEditor

            Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook

            Set xlWorksheet = xlBook.Worksheet("Worksheet_tab")

            Set olWordTable = olWordDoc.Tables(1)

            olWordTable.Range.Copy

            xlWorksheet.Paste Destination:=xlWorksheet.Range("B2")

        End If
    End If
Next olItems

End Sub
```

Comment: Step through with F5. Fix all the typos then paste that code into the question.

Comment: Not all items are mail items. you have to loop like this `For Each Item In olInboxFolder.Items` and then `If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then`

Comment: You should have seen an error in `Set olInboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olInboxFolder)` it should be`Set olInboxFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`. As well `Dim olItem as Object` then `For each olItem in olItems`.

Comment: It is probably better to use the prefix "my" rather than "ol" so there is no confusion with terms already in use in VBA.

Comment: New to stackoverflow so I dont know how to reply to each individual comment, but thank you all!

Comment: To reply say @ThepersonName

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical solution. Not practical on my machine.

- Generates multiple messages per iteration "Code execution has been interrupted".
- Can force Outlook to restart

Prior question indicating unreliability [Copying Tables from Outlook Email to Excel File - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678249/copying-tables-from-outlook-email-to-excel-file-vba).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportOutlookTableToExcel()

Dim olInspector As Inspector
Dim olInboxFolder As folder

Dim olItems As items
Dim olItem As Object

Dim olWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim olWordTable As Word.Table

'Declare Excel Variables
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Create a new Excel workbook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True

Set olInboxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItems = olInboxFolder.items

Dim Start_date As Date
Dim End_date As Date

Start_date = #7/31/2022# + TimeSerial(5, 0, 0)
Debug.Print " Start_date: " & Start_date

End_date = #8/15/2022# + TimeSerial(5, 0, 0)
Debug.Print " End_date: " & End_date

'Continue (or debug) when there is a message.
' "Code execution has been interrupted"

'For efficiency, implement a Restrict on the dates.
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884195
' This as well will reduce the number of messages.

For Each olItem In olInboxFolder.items
    
    If olItem.Class = olMail Then
    
        If olItem.CreationTime >= Start_date Then
        
            If olItem.CreationTime <= End_date Then
            
                If olItems.subject = "Email subject" Then
                
                    Debug.Print olItem.subject
                    Debug.Print " CreationTime: " & olItem.CreationTime
                                                            
                    Set olInspector = olItem.GetInspector
                    Set olWordDoc = olInspector.WordEditor
                    
                    If olWordDoc.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                        Set olWordTable = olWordDoc.Tables(1)
                        
                        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
                        Set xlWorksheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
                        
                        olWordTable.Range.Copy
                        xlWorksheet.Paste Destination:=xlWorksheet.Range("B2")
                        
                        Debug.Print " Table saved."
                        
                    Else
                        Debug.Print " Table not found. ****"
                        
                    End If 
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

Debug.Print "Done."

End Sub
```