# Date filter to extract Outlook mails

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to create a ticketing system for a shared mailbox I share with a team in my company.

I'd like to extract mail information received on a given day.

The date filter I created:

```vb
Sub List_Email_Info()
    
    Dim i As Long     
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItems As Items
    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim FilterString As String

    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInboxFolder = olNS.Folders("xyz.europe@xyz.com").Folders("Inbox")
    Set olItems = olInboxFolder.Items 

    FilterString = "[ReceivedTime] >= 30 - 08 - 2021"

    i = 1

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each olMailItem In olItems.Restrict(FilterString)
    
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = olItems(i).ReceivedTime
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = olItems(i).Subject
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = olItems(i).SenderName
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = olItems(i).Body
    
        i = i + 1

    Next olMailItem

    Sheets("Test").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    MsgBox "Export complete.", vbInformation

    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInboxFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/restrict-outlook-items-by-date/38316430) help you? Your format looks wrong, try `[ReceivedTime]>=30/08/2021 00:00`

Comment: Think your error is in the FilterString = line try   FilterString = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format("30/08/2021 00:01am", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter date must be a *string*: [Items.Restrict method (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Then adjust for errors and typos:

```vb
Sub List_Email_Info()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olItems As Items
    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim FilterString As String
    
    Set OlApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInboxFolder = olNS.Folders("xyz.europe@xyz.com").Folders("Inbox") ' Localised.
    Set olItems = olInboxFolder.Items
    
    Const FilterDate As Date = #8/20/2021#
    
    FilterString = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(FilterDate, "ddddd h:nn") & "'"
    
    For Each olMailItem In olItems.Restrict(FilterString)
        Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = olMailItem.ReceivedTime
        Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = olMailItem.Subject
        Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = olMailItem.SenderName
        Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = olMailItem.Body
    Next
    
    Sheets("Test").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    MsgBox "Export complete.", vbInformation
    
    Set olItems = Nothing
    Set olInboxFolder = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook evaluates date-time values according to the time format, short date format, and long date format settings in the Regional and Language Options applet in the Windows Control Panel. In particular, Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds. If you specify seconds in the date-time comparison string, the filter will not operate as expected.

Although dates and times are typically stored with a date format, filters using the Jet and DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax require that the date-time value to be converted to a string representation. In Jet syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in either double quotes or single quotes. In DASL syntax, the date-time comparison string should be enclosed in single quotes.

To make sure that the date-time comparison string is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the Visual Basic for Applications Format function (or its equivalent in your programming language). The following example creates a Jet filter to find all items that have been received before June 12, 2021 at 3:30 P.M local time.

```
criteria = "[ReceivedTime] < '" & Format("6/12/2021 3:30PM","General Date") & "'"
```

Also you can specify a hard-coded date string in the following way:

```
FilterString = "[ReceivedTime] > `30/08/2021`"
```