# Filter calendar meetings by date using the Restrict method

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

I am trying to extract future calendar events from Outlook using the `Items.Restrict` method.

If the filter is not applied, it returns more than 70 results, older and future events.
When the filter for future events is applied, it returns around 20 results, most of them, future events, but **also some old ones**.

The [Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict) filter is partially working, but I cannot understand why is not filtering those few old events.

```
Dim oOutlook            As Object
Dim oMAPI               As Object
Dim oAppointments       As Object
Dim oFilteredAppointments As Object
Dim oAppointmentItem    As Object
Dim sFilter             As String
Const olFolderCalendar = 9

Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set oMAPI = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oAppointments = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

sFilter = "[Start]>'" & Date & "'"
Debug.Print sFilter
Set oFilteredAppointments = oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sFilter)

For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilteredAppointments
    Debug.Print oAppointmentItem.Start
Next
```

To show some evidence of the filter and the results I'm getting:
[image: Immediate window showing wrong results]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict Outlook Items by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/restrict-outlook-items-by-date)

Comment: Not really, the question is about items that are out of the filtering range showing up. Before posting here, just in case I tried applying an upper and lower filter like in your suggestions, but the result is the same.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print oAppointmentItem.Start, oAppointmentItem.Subject`. You should find the  old ones are the first occurrence of recurring events. With `.IncludeRecurrences` you get the future occurrences in the specified period.

Answer (score 2):

Calendars are trickier than normal folders. I had to combine the two filters as was suggested in [Restrict Outlook Items by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/restrict-outlook-items-by-date).

Note: `oAppointmentItems` rather than `oAppointments.Items`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub calApptsInSpecifiedRange()

    Dim oCalendarFolder         As Folder
    Dim oAppointmentItems       As Items
    Dim oFilteredAppointments   As Items
    
    Dim oAppointmentItem        As Object
    Dim sFilter                 As String
    
    Set oCalendarFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set oAppointmentItems = oCalendarFolder.Items
    
    oAppointmentItems.Sort "[Start]", False
    oAppointmentItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
    sFilter = "[Start] > '" & Date & "'" & " AND [Start] < " & "'" & Date + 30 & "'"
    Debug.Print sFilter
    Set oFilteredAppointments = oAppointmentItems.Restrict(sFilter)
    
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilteredAppointments
        Debug.Print oAppointmentItem.Start, oAppointmentItem.Subject
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Finally! Your code does exactly what I was trying. However, the problem was not in the filter. In my code, I set ```Set oAppointments = oMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)``` and then include the recurring events and sort them using ```oAppointments.Items.IncludeRecurrences``` and ```oAppointments.Items.Sort```, lastly applied the filter as ```oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sFilter)```. This way doesn't work.

Comment: In your code you additionally ```Set oAppointmentItems = oAppointments.Items``` and then use ```oAppointmentItems.IncludeRecurrences``` and ```oAppointmentItems.Sort``` and lastly ```oAppointmentItems.Restrict(sFilter)```. I don't understand the difference between the 2 ways, but if you could explain it, I will prefer to mark this as the right solution.

Comment: Another strange behaviour is that in order to work properly, ```IncludeRecurrences``` has to always be true. When it's off, it always returns the non-recurring events within the filtered range, plus the first occurrence of the series, even if it's out of the filtered range.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all Outlook appointment items from the folder that meets the predefined condition, you need to [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866960.aspx) the items in ascending order and set the `IncludeRecurrences` to true. You will not catch recurrent appointments if you don’t do this before using the Restrict method. Read more about that in the [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/) article.

Also you may find the [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/) article helpful.

Dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the Format function. The following example creates a filter to find all contacts that have been modified after January 15, 2022 at 3:30 P.M.

```
sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/2022 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```

Comment: Sorting them produces the same result but sorted, it doesn't solve it.

The filter is contained in a string variable, so I don't think that's the problem either.

I'll try to do it using ```Find``` as an alternative, but I was curious about the cause of the problem with ```Restrict```.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Format` method to get the date string formatted as Outlook understands?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it before posting here, but no effect.

Comment: How does your code look like with `Format` and other changes mentioned in my post?

Comment: With 2 the new lines before the filter: ```oAppointments.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True``` and ```oAppointments.Items.Sort "[Start]"```. And the filter as ```sFilter = "[Start]>'" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "'"```. The problem is still the same. I've also tried different formats for the date and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: (!) Do not try the above code without turning off ```IncludeRecurrences``` or applying another extra filter to limit the results to a period between 2 dates. Otherwise, it will loop for many millions of recurrent meetings.

Comment: Yeah, the article I mentioned clearly states that.