Restrict by Date in Outlook VBA only able to filter todays mail
I've created working code for filing emails by Input box for date in Outlook. However, the filter only works for the current day. Any other day before that it does not find any emails under the matching criteria.
It works by converting the inputted date (the date of reports that must be filed) into the date the emails are received (the following day). However this code only works correctly to filter emails received today. It filters them correctly, but cannot find any days previous to that.
I've used the 2x restrict filter option to select a date using the Microsoft advised formatting. I've tried adjusting the filtering so it only uses a lower bound, and I've checked that when removing the date filter it can still find the emails from the sender. The moment a date filter is applied to any mail received before the current day, it can no longer find the mail.
Sub EmailSort()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Mfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim InboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, DestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sharedmailbox As Outlook.Recipient
Dim olattachment As Outlook.Attachments
Dim sendername As String, datestring As String, attachname As String
Dim i As Long, cont As Long, ii As Long
Dim sfilter As String, ssavepath As String, sdate As String, spathdate As String, yearr As String
Dim dateformat As Date
Dim NSWB As Boolean


Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedmailbox = olNamespace.CreateRecipient("admin")
Set InboxFolder = olNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedmailbox, olFolderInbox)
Set DestFolder = InboxFolder.Folders("STATES")
dateformat = InputBox("Please Choose the date you'd like to sort (dd/mm/yyyy)", "Date Selector")
spathdate = Replace(dateformat, "/", "")
yearr = Right(spathdate, 2)
sdate = Replace(dateformat, "/", " ")
spathdate = Replace(spathdate, Right(spathdate, 4), yearr)
If Len(spathdate) < 6 Then sdate = "0" & sdate
If Len(spathdate) < 6 Then spathdate = "0" & spathdate
dateformat = dateformat + 1

sfilter = "[Sendername] = ""senderemail"""
sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] < '" & Format(dateformat + 1, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] > '" & Format(dateformat, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
Set olItems = InboxFolder.Items.Restrict(sfilter)
i = olItems.Count
If olItems.Count > 0 Then


Did you check that sFilter looks like what you expect?   That Format() looks odd to me.

dateformat is a string, but you add an int to it. Try to convert it to date using CDATE first. And do post the value of sfilter before you pass it to Restrict.

Not sure this is the issue but outlook search generally doesnt recognize And as an operator - it has to be uppercase AND

that is the advised Format from previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/restrict-outlook-items-by-date
the sfilter looks like I expect. Print.debug returns [Sendername] = "noreply=smartaindustrial.com@mg.smartaindustrial.com" And [ReceivedTime] > 'Tuesday 00:00' And [ReceivedTime] < 'Wednesday 00:00'
I have used uppercase AND and that hasn't affected the filter.
it seems to convert correctly based on the debug.print window. Can you please explain "post the value of sfilter before passing to restrict"?

InputBox returns a string. Convert to a date.
and/or
Format(dateFormat + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")

Format(dateFormat, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")

Option Explicit

Sub EmailFilter()

Dim inboxFolder As folder
Dim olItems As Items

Dim dateString As String
Dim dateFormat As Date

Dim sfilter As String

Set inboxFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Day and month can swap unexpectedly.
' When testing use a day less than 13 and a month different than day.
'dateString = InputBox("Please choose the date you'd like to filter (dd/mm/yyyy)", "Date Selector")
dateString = InputBox("Choose date to filter (dd/mm/yyyy)", "Date Selector", "12/05/2024")

Debug.Print "dateString...............................................: " & dateString

' I get 2024-12-05, day and month interchanged. Can occur when day is less than 13.
dateFormat = CDate(dateString)
Debug.Print "CDate(dateString)........................................: " & dateFormat

' I get 2024-12-05, day and month interchanged. Can occur when day is less than 13.
dateFormat = CDate(year(dateString) & "-" & Month(dateString) & "-" & day(dateString))
Debug.Print "CDate(year(dateString)-Month(dateString)-day(dateString)): " & dateFormat

' I get 2024-12-05, day and month interchanged. Can occur when day is less than 13.
dateFormat = CDate(year(dateString) & "-" & Month(dateString) & "-" & day(dateString))
Debug.Print "CDate(Month(dateString)-day(dateString)-year(dateString)): " & dateFormat

' I get 2024-05-12
dateFormat = CDate(day(dateString) & "-" & Month(dateString) & "-" & year(dateString))
Debug.Print "CDate(day(dateString)-Month(dateString)-year(dateString)): " & dateFormat

Debug.Print
sfilter = "[Sendername] = ""sender name"""

'sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] < '" & Format(dateformat + 1, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] < '" & Format(dateFormat + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"

'sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] > '" & Format(dateformat, "dddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sfilter = sfilter & " And [SentOn] >= '" & Format(dateFormat, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
Debug.Print sfilter

Debug.Print
Set olItems = inboxFolder.Items
Debug.Print "Original olItems.count..: " & olItems.count
Set olItems = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict(sfilter)
Debug.Print "Restricted olItems.count: " & olItems.count
Debug.Print

End Sub


I have added all these changes and adopted the dateformat as date you've provided. There has been no change to how the filtering works.
I've tried individually testing the upper and lower date filters to restrict. I'm currently testing an email sent on a Tuesday at 08:46.
With the 'sfilter [Sendername] = "noreply=smartaindustrial.com@mg.smartaindustrial.com" AND [ReceivedTime] < 'Wednesday 12:00 AM'" it counts the email. With sfilter [Sendername] = "noreply=smartaindustrial.com@mg.smartaindustrial.com" AND [ReceivedTime] > 'Tuesday 12:00 AM' it does not count the email.

I've now tested that any [ReceivedTime] > greater than statement it will not count, regardless of the date. it will count any [ReceivedTime] < Lesser than statement, regardless of the date.

Try Format(dateFormat + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM")  with five ds. [Sendername] = "noreply=smartaindustrial.com@mg.smartaindustrial.com" And [SentOn] < '2024-05-15 12:00 AM' And [SentOn] >= '2024-05-14 12:00 AM'

More testing. It will count ANY email from the sender when using [Received time] > Statement. It won't count any email when using '[ReceivedTime] <`. If you use both, it will only count emails from the previous day, not any farther back than that.

the five d's got it. Thank you so much sorry for not counting properly.
